# Android getContentResolver() is undefined for getting AndroidID

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get Android's device Id in my class and a function will use it. When I try to use like below, it says 'The method getContentResolver() is undefined'
How to fix it do you have any idea ?

**Update:**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // db version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // db name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);


    // constructor
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

}
```

Comment: extend the class that has it or implement it yourself?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the proper Context, like so:

```
Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

However, before using ANDROID_ID you might want to google it a bit, as it's problematic, and not always unique, consistent or even defined.

In order to access `getApplicationContext()`, you'll need a `Context`. Fix your class declaration:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Context ctx;

    public MyClass( Context ctx ) {
        super();
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return Secure.getString( this.ctx.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }

    ....
}
```

Then when you instantiate your class within an activity, do:

```
MyClass idClass = new MyClass( this );
```

Another note -- class names should begin with an upper case character.

Comment: but, still the same error "The method getApplicationContext() is undefined "

Comment: Then you need to pass in the `Context` into the class. See above.

Comment: You left some extra code in: `this.ctx.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()`, you already have `ctx` so you don't need to call `ctx.getApplicationContext()`. (upvote)

Comment: Keeping the getApplicationContext() in there can be helpful in cases when you want to decouple from the calling activity's context. But you're correct, it's generally not needed.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, i need to use the deviceId in super, something like super(getID()), but it gives an error saying "Cannot refer to an instance method while explicitly invoking a constructor"

Comment: Methinks you do not know what "super()" means.

Comment: okay, i updated my code, this explains what I want, so i want to give a dynamic name for the database how to do that?

Comment: Sounds like a new question? You might want to add that. This helps folks who have similar problems find the answers better. Good luck!

Comment: @JohnSmith: Using `ANDROID_ID` for a "dynamic name for the database" is pointless. Each device has its own `ANDROID_ID` value, and so this name is not especially "dynamic". You would be better served using a simple hard-coded database name. If you truly believe that you have a justifiable reason for having "a dynamic name for the database", ask a fresh StackOverflow question, explaining *completely and precisely* the characteristics you are hoping to get from "a dynamic name for the database", so we can give you more specific advice.